# PostgreSQL Domain: no numbers

Tags: postgresql, dns

Does anyone know if there is a way to enter alphabetic characters only but no numbers?
I thought about something like this

```
CREATE DOMAIN countryDomain AS VARCHAR(100)
    CHECK( VALUE ??? );
```

And then ??? is gonna be something like NO INTEGER. Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: What about non-digit, non-letter characters like `"§$%& ...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex would be a simple option:

```
CREATE DOMAIN countryDomain AS VARCHAR(100)
CHECK(VALUE ~ E'^[a-zA-z]*$')
```

Adjust the regex to match the precise character set you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I've been looking for. I'm new to SQL so I didn't know there are such easy ways. :)

Comment: You might want to spend some time with the [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/index.html), it is fairly extensive but reasonably well organized/indexed and readable.

Answer (score 2):

To just exclude digits, you might want to tackle this the other way round:

```
CREATE DOMAIN country_domain AS text
CHECK(VALUE ~ '^[^0-9]*$');
```

Or use the [Regular Expression Class-shorthand Escape](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CLASS-SHORTHAND-ESCAPES-TABLE) `\D` for that purpose precisely:

```
...
CHECK(VALUE ~ '^\D*$');
```